# I want to optimize the code in python to reduce the time

Tags: python, nested-loops, execution-time

I got the following Python code :

```py
newArr = []

for i in range(0 , len(customers)):
    sum = 1
    for j in range(i+1 , len(customers)):
        if customers[i] == customers[j] :
            sum += 1

    sum = (sum/len(customers)) * 100
    if sum >= 5:
        newArr.append(customers[i])

newArr = set(newArr)
newArr = list(newArr)
newArr.sort()
return newArr
```

What can I do to optimize the code and reduce the execution time?

Comment: the customers is a list given by the user

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of duplicates? Try making use of `set(customers)`, which will contain only the unique values.

Comment: no i want to count the number of each type of customers @zvone

Comment: So why do you return ````newArr````?

Comment: Have a look at [python's builtin Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is basically meant for that and is way faster.

Comment: please provide an exazmple of customers list and the expected result and/or explain clearly what is supposed to do the function.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, once you found out a type of customer consists of more than 5% of the customers you want to append and later return it (sorted). So it is sufficient to count the customers by type and return only those who pass that threshold -

```
from collections import Counter

customers_counter = Counter(customers)
threshold = int(5 * len(customers)/100 -1)

output_list = []
customers_counter = {k:v for k, v in customers_counter.items() if v > threshold}

return sorted(customers_counter.keys())
```